# Web Application entirely through client

Tags: javascript, web

I do not have the privileged nor the permission to ask for a server in my workplace thus I was thinking of developing a local web application on my computer and utilizing a common space folder to let everyone access my web based tool.

How can I use a client to entirely develop a web application, query database, and do all the things that you'd generally do using a server?

Comment: see https://www.vagrantup.com/  You can install on your local machine an image of your production webserver.

Comment: What you have described is a server. It doesn't matter if it's your own computer or some other compter in a data center. If you don't have a permission to set up a server in your workplace, you're likely to get in trouble if you try to work around the rules.

Comment: I know what I have described is a server. That's the point of the question. I think I'm just really interested in reading in values from a database (say oracle)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can accomplish what you're talking about through a browser app alone. Modern browsers have local database storage, but without a server you simply can't have central data that everyone can access.

Why not set up a local server on your own machine? Node.js servers are very easy to set up and perfect for simple use cases. Your coworkers could access the app via your IP address anytime it is running and your computer is on the network.

For more specific information please ask a more targeted question; this question is too open-ended to have a clear answer.